# How to match begin of expression and exclude it?

Tags: regex

I've a string SRE("Documents", with: "For boss") and I want to match string inside "" but without "".

I've come to regex `\"([a-zA-Z0-9\s?]+)` but in result I can see `["Documents, "For boss]`.

How the regex should looks like to exclude also first "?

Comment: What implementation of regex?

Comment: Assuming your language supports it (since you haven't specified which language, there's no way for us to know), you can use a positive lookbehind: `(?<=")[^"]+` or even reset the pattern using `\K` as such `"\K[^"]+`. Otherwise, you'll have to group it like this `"([^"]+)"` and access capture group 1's value.

Comment: @ctwheels [`"\K[^"]+` would give 4 matches on `SRE("Documents", with: "For boss")`](https://regex101.com/r/q3Iam7/1/)

Comment: I think your original expresion is correct, you only need to use the captured group instead of the full match

Comment: @bobblebubble oops you're right

Comment: [`/(?<=")[\w\s]+[^"]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/pHknb4/1/) to be specific.

Comment: as long as there is no word character or [space after the second `"`](https://regex101.com/r/pHknb4/2)

Answer (score 2):

Try `"([^"]*)"`, where `[^"]` means matching a single character which is not `"`.